# Multiple time windows vrp [or-tools]

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I have an implementation that is supposed to set multiple time windows for a shipment:

```py
    def _set_allowed_time_window(time_dimension, index, time_windows: list):
        """ Sets the appropriate time windows for a node. """
        # ortools lacks a function to set a list of time windows
        # workaround is to set the min and max of a list of sorted time windows as the allowed range
        # and then to restrict the times in between the allowed time windows
        # see https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/456 and
        # https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/MBq1TcqSQTI
        earliest_start = int(time_windows[0][0])
        latest_end = int(time_windows[len(time_windows)-1][1])
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(earliest_start, latest_end)

        for tw_index, time_window in enumerate(time_windows):
            if tw_index == len(time_windows)-1:
                break
            time_window_end = int(time_window[1])
            next_time_window_start = int(time_windows[tw_index+1][0])

            time_dimension.CumulVar(index).RemoveInterval(time_window_end, next_time_window_start)
```

There seems to be nothing wrong logically, yet or-tools is unable to return a solution unless I remove the line `time_dimension.CumulVar(index).RemoveInterval(time_window_end, next_time_window_start)`. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here ?

Here `time_windows` is a lis, e.g: [[100, 200], [300, 400]] and `index` is the index retrieved from `NodeToIndex`.

Comment: Not getting a solution doesn't always mean there's something wrong with the code. It might be the case that there is no feasible solution for the problem when you remove [200-300] from the time window

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah I understand that. I should add that each node is optional (by the use of `AddDisjunction`), and the time windows are pretty wide. So the model should at least assign some shipments to some vehicles, even if it doesn't assign everything, right ?

Comment: I actually ran into a same problem. I just had to tweak my penalty for dropping a node (it wasn't less than the cost but still all nodes were being dropped). Can you share code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: you may try to use a different FirstSolutionStrategy too, most of them are bad at backtracking and won't use kind of brute force to walk the entire search space

Comment: @MoosaSaadat  I tried changing the penalty term for dropping the node. The solver seems to move past `root node processed` when I reduce the penalty term to 1. It gets stuck at `root node processed` for very high values. Shouldn't it drop shipments to make a solution feasible ?

Comment: @Mizux any recommendations for a good first solution strategy that is not so bad at backtracking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems indeed to be in the FirstSolutionStrategy as mentioned in the comments. When everything comes out unassigned or-tools is simply unable to build a first solution. Unfortunately this is not very clear from the logs. I have had success with the `FirstSolutionStrategy`s `ALL_UNEPRFORMED` and `PATH_MOST_CONSTRAINED_ARC`.

Unfortunately in my case `ALL_UNPERFORMED` was unable to solve trivial cases, but `PATH_MOST_COSNTRAINED_ARC` worked well. I just wish that the algorithms has more in-depth descriptions so it is easier to select the proper algorithm.